# android proguard: how to change the mapping.txt name and location

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

The default proguard file name and location:

```
build\outputs\mapping\release\mapping.txt
```

The file needs to be checked in for every release for retrace. it is better not to put it under build (which can be deleted by gradle clean).

add the followings to proguard-rules.pro

```
-printmapping foo/mapping
-printseeds   foo/seeds
-printusage   foo/usage
```

NOT working. Is there way to set its location and name?